Linear mixed model EMMEANS using multiply imputed datasets (mids) adds level to factor variable
I'm using a multiply imputed dataset (mids) to run a linear mixed model in R, and then I tried the emmeans package to obtain my emmeans with p-values. X2 is a factor which I'm interested in, that was multiply imputed as a factor, 0,1.
library(foreign)
library(mice)
library(broom.mixed)
library(lme4)
library(emmeans)

Some of my df1 data (dput):
  structure(list(imp = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5), Subj = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 
3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 
10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 15, 
15, 15, 16, 16, 16, 17, 17, 17, 18, 18, 18, 19, 19, 19, 20, 20, 
20, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 
7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 13, 
13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 15, 16, 16, 16, 17, 17, 17, 18, 18, 
18, 19, 19, 19, 20, 20, 20, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 
4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 11, 
11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 15, 16, 16, 
16, 17, 17, 17, 18, 18, 18, 19, 19, 19, 20, 20, 20, 1, 1, 1, 
2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 
9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 14, 
14, 14, 15, 15, 15, 16, 16, 16, 17, 17, 17, 18, 18, 18, 19, 19, 
19, 20, 20, 20, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 
6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 12, 
12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 15, 16, 16, 16, 17, 17, 
17, 18, 18, 18, 19, 19, 19, 20, 20, 20, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 
3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 10, 
10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 
15, 16, 16, 16, 17, 17, 17, 18, 18, 18, 19, 19, 19, 20, 20, 20
), X1 = c(0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 
3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 
3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 
3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 
3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 
3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 
3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 
3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 
3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 
3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 
3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 
3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 
3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 
3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 
3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 
3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 
3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 
3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3), X2 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), X3 = c(28, 28, 
28, 37, 37, 37, 36, 36, 36, 57, 57, 57, 34, 34, 34, 53, 53, 53, 
42, 42, 42, 25, 25, 25, 29, 29, 29, 21, 21, 21, 52, 52, 52, 23, 
23, 23, 39, 39, 39, 49, 49, 49, 39, 39, 39, 30, 30, 30, 65, 65, 
65, 35, 35, 35, 34, 34, 34, 42, 42, 42, 28, 28, 28, 37, 37, 37, 
36, 36, 36, 57, 57, 57, 34, 34, 34, 53, 53, 53, 42, 42, 42, 25, 
25, 25, 29, 29, 29, 21, 21, 21, 52, 52, 52, 23, 23, 23, 39, 39, 
39, 49, 49, 49, 39, 39, 39, 30, 30, 30, 65, 65, 65, 35, 35, 35, 
34, 34, 34, 42, 42, 42, 28, 28, 28, 37, 37, 37, 36, 36, 36, 57, 
57, 57, 34, 34, 34, 53, 53, 53, 42, 42, 42, 25, 25, 25, 29, 29, 
29, 21, 21, 21, 52, 52, 52, 23, 23, 23, 39, 39, 39, 49, 49, 49, 
39, 39, 39, 30, 30, 30, 65, 65, 65, 35, 35, 35, 34, 34, 34, 42, 
42, 42, 28, 28, 28, 37, 37, 37, 36, 36, 36, 57, 57, 57, 34, 34, 
34, 53, 53, 53, 42, 42, 42, 25, 25, 25, 29, 29, 29, 21, 21, 21, 
52, 52, 52, 23, 23, 23, 39, 39, 39, 49, 49, 49, 39, 39, 39, 30, 
30, 30, 65, 65, 65, 35, 35, 35, 34, 34, 34, 42, 42, 42, 28, 28, 
28, 37, 37, 37, 36, 36, 36, 57, 57, 57, 34, 34, 34, 53, 53, 53, 
42, 42, 42, 25, 25, 25, 29, 29, 29, 21, 21, 21, 52, 52, 52, 23, 
23, 23, 39, 39, 39, 49, 49, 49, 39, 39, 39, 30, 30, 30, 65, 65, 
65, 35, 35, 35, 34, 34, 34, 42, 42, 42, 28, 28, 28, 37, 37, 37, 
36, 36, 36, 57, 57, 57, 34, 34, 34, 53, 53, 53, 42, 42, 42, 25, 
25, 25, 29, 29, 29, 21, 21, 21, 52, 52, 52, 23, 23, 23, 39, 39, 
39, 49, 49, 49, 39, 39, 39, 30, 30, 30, 65, 65, 65, 35, 35, 35, 
34, 34, 34, 42, 42, 42), X4 = c(2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 
1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 
2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 
1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 
2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 
1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 
2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1), X5 = c(2, 2, 2, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 
2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
    Dependant = c(32, 11, 25, 30, 10, 8, 34, NA, NA, 16, 20, 
    20.5, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 12, 21, NA, 20, 41, 25, 26, 24, 
    28, 33, 16, 6, 3, 7, 0, NA, 17, 3, NA, 40, 25, 21, 35, NA, 
    NA, 17, 5, 4, 27, 8, 4, 22, 20, NA, 18, 23, 10, 13, 14, 4, 
    15, 12, 14, 32, 11, 25, 30, 10, 8, 34, 22.74679565, 9.078754233, 
    16, 20, 20.5, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 12, 21, 23.89331785, 20, 
    41, 25, 26, 24, 28, 33, 16, 6, 3, 7, 0, 9.563034676, 17, 
    3, 8.171110057, 40, 25, 21, 35, 13.53468633, 21.4990267, 
    17, 5, 4, 27, 8, 4, 22, 20, 10.75448127, 18, 23, 10, 13, 
    14, 4, 15, 12, 14, 32, 11, 25, 30, 10, 8, 34, 23.678318, 
    6.38024107, 16, 20, 20.5, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 12, 21, 15.33803817, 
    20, 41, 25, 26, 24, 28, 33, 16, 6, 3, 7, 0, 26.37095017, 
    17, 3, 5.8830194, 40, 25, 21, 35, 17.5314952, 13.24750912, 
    17, 5, 4, 27, 8, 4, 22, 20, 16.64639694, 18, 23, 10, 13, 
    14, 4, 15, 12, 14, 32, 11, 25, 30, 10, 8, 34, 24.23722065, 
    14.13450552, 16, 20, 20.5, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 12, 21, 21.8956743, 
    20, 41, 25, 26, 24, 28, 33, 16, 6, 3, 7, 0, 13.31806771, 
    17, 3, 12.46910086, 40, 25, 21, 35, 5.346067919, 14.71408964, 
    17, 5, 4, 27, 8, 4, 22, 20, 9.644988209, 18, 23, 10, 13, 
    14, 4, 15, 12, 14, 32, 11, 25, 30, 10, 8, 34, 16.25464311, 
    14.55203722, 16, 20, 20.5, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 12, 21, 20.15197466, 
    20, 41, 25, 26, 24, 28, 33, 16, 6, 3, 7, 0, 7.169741223, 
    17, 3, 15.89606111, 40, 25, 21, 35, 8.178602917, -2.653330003, 
    17, 5, 4, 27, 8, 4, 22, 20, 17.11276677, 18, 23, 10, 13, 
    14, 4, 15, 12, 14, 32, 11, 25, 30, 10, 8, 34, 28.30217443, 
    7.983293096, 16, 20, 20.5, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 12, 21, -2.445506679, 
    20, 41, 25, 26, 24, 28, 33, 16, 6, 3, 7, 0, 0.897162825, 
    17, 3, 12.38497675, 40, 25, 21, 35, 13.76105932, 23.24251938, 
    17, 5, 4, 27, 8, 4, 22, 20, 9.744084982, 18, 23, 10, 13, 
    14, 4, 15, 12, 14)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-360L), variable.labels = c(imp = "", Subj = "", X1 = "Temps", 
X2 = "PsychoT1", X3 = "T0_age", X4 = "Group", X5 = "Sexe", Dependant = "Dependant"
), codepage = 65001L)

df.mids1<-as.mids(long=df1, .imp="imp")
yPsy1 <- with(data = df.mids1, exp = lme4::lmer(Dependant ~ factor(X1) + 
                                                  factor(X2) + 
                                                  X3 + 
                                                  factor(X4) + 
                                                  factor(X5) + 
                                                  factor(X1) * factor(X2) + 
                                                  factor(X2) * factor(X4) + 
                                                  factor(X1) * factor(X4) +
                                                  factor(X1) * factor(X2) * factor(X4) + 
                                                  (1| Subj)), reml=TRUE)
mice.res <- summary(pool(yPsy1))
mice.res
#>                                   term    estimate std.error   statistic
#> 1                          (Intercept)  25.9340792 7.8864719  3.28842599
#> 2                          factor(X1)1 -11.0168803 6.1641328 -1.78725552
#> 3                          factor(X1)3 -12.8614164 6.5151402 -1.97408128
#> 4                          factor(X2)1   7.6964991 7.2210293  1.06584516
#> 5                                   X3  -0.1129837 0.1455105 -0.77646422
#> 6                          factor(X4)2  -6.6860358 7.3265611 -0.91257490
#> 7                          factor(X5)2   6.7636729 4.4682356  1.51372343
#> 8              factor(X1)1:factor(X2)1  -2.5189278 7.1551292 -0.35204505
#> 9              factor(X1)3:factor(X2)1  -1.8445553 7.8818619 -0.23402533
#> 10             factor(X2)1:factor(X4)2  -4.2784766 8.7986350 -0.48626595
#> 11             factor(X1)1:factor(X4)2   8.7468803 7.6738824  1.13982465
#> 12             factor(X1)3:factor(X4)2   6.1926579 7.7724684  0.79674276
#> 13 factor(X1)1:factor(X2)1:factor(X4)2  -0.6267509 9.4682741 -0.06619485
#> 14 factor(X1)3:factor(X2)1:factor(X4)2   6.0615966 9.6874709  0.62571507
#>          df    p.value
#> 1  36.93801 0.00221774
#> 2  42.12344 0.08109302
#> 3  34.16544 0.05650184
#> 4  31.15342 0.29468469
#> 5  34.29064 0.44279816
#> 6  36.25076 0.36749560
#> 7  41.83535 0.13761496
#> 8  40.67191 0.72662209
#> 9  25.35173 0.81684491
#> 10 36.72275 0.62966797
#> 11 39.75094 0.26118111
#> 12 37.82968 0.43057262
#> 13 34.49832 0.94760483
#> 14 30.61215 0.53613943

emmeans(yPsy1, pairwise ~ X1|X2|X4)
#> $emmeans
#> X2 = 0.0, X4 = 1:
#>  X1 emmean   SE   df lower.CL upper.CL
#>   0   25.0 6.58 18.0   11.152     38.8
#>   1   13.9 6.56 18.1    0.172     27.7
#>   3   12.1 6.18 21.7   -0.732     24.9
#> 
#> X2 = 0.6, X4 = 1:
#>  X1 emmean   SE   df lower.CL upper.CL
#>   0   25.0 6.58 18.0   11.152     38.8
#>   1   13.9 6.56 18.1    0.172     27.7
#>   3   12.1 6.18 21.7   -0.732     24.9
#> 
#> X2 = 0.8, X4 = 1:
#>  X1 emmean   SE   df lower.CL upper.CL
#>   0   25.0 6.58 18.0   11.152     38.8
#>   1   13.9 6.56 18.1    0.172     27.7
#>   3   12.1 6.18 21.7   -0.732     24.9
#> 
#> X2 = 1.0, X4 = 1:
#>  X1 emmean   SE   df lower.CL upper.CL
#>   0   32.7 3.65 21.4   25.071     40.3
#>   1   19.1 3.85 18.1   11.037     27.2
#>   3   18.0 3.97 16.1    9.540     26.4
#> 
#> X2 = 0.0, X4 = 2:
#>  X1 emmean   SE   df lower.CL upper.CL
#>   0   18.3 4.68 20.9    8.540     28.0
#>   1   16.0 5.01 16.9    5.437     26.6
#>   3   11.6 4.68 20.8    1.869     21.4
#> 
#> X2 = 0.6, X4 = 2:
#>  X1 emmean   SE   df lower.CL upper.CL
#>   0   18.3 4.68 20.9    8.540     28.0
#>   1   16.0 5.01 16.9    5.437     26.6
#>   3   11.6 4.68 20.8    1.869     21.4
#> 
#> X2 = 0.8, X4 = 2:
#>  X1 emmean   SE   df lower.CL upper.CL
#>   0   18.3 4.68 20.9    8.540     28.0
#>   1   16.0 5.01 16.9    5.437     26.6
#>   3   11.6 4.68 20.8    1.869     21.4
#> 
#> X2 = 1.0, X4 = 2:
#>  X1 emmean   SE   df lower.CL upper.CL
#>   0   21.7 3.42 23.1   14.630     28.8
#>   1   16.3 3.72 17.3    8.434     24.1
#>   3   19.2 3.50 21.7   11.981     26.5
#> 
#> Results are averaged over the levels of: X5 
#> Confidence level used: 0.95 
#> 
#> $contrasts
#> X2 = 0.0, X4 = 1:
#>  contrast  estimate   SE   df t.ratio p.value
#>  X10 - X11    11.02 6.16 30.2   1.787  0.1909
#>  X10 - X13    12.86 6.52 25.1   1.974  0.1394
#>  X11 - X13     1.84 6.50 25.4   0.284  0.9567
#> 
#> X2 = 0.6, X4 = 1:
#>  contrast  estimate   SE   df t.ratio p.value
#>  X10 - X11    11.02 6.16 30.2   1.787  0.1909
#>  X10 - X13    12.86 6.52 25.1   1.974  0.1394
#>  X11 - X13     1.84 6.50 25.4   0.284  0.9567
#> 
#> X2 = 0.8, X4 = 1:
#>  contrast  estimate   SE   df t.ratio p.value
#>  X10 - X11    11.02 6.16 30.2   1.787  0.1909
#>  X10 - X13    12.86 6.52 25.1   1.974  0.1394
#>  X11 - X13     1.84 6.50 25.4   0.284  0.9567
#> 
#> X2 = 1.0, X4 = 1:
#>  contrast  estimate   SE   df t.ratio p.value
#>  X10 - X11    13.54 3.63 25.1   3.725  0.0028
#>  X10 - X13    14.71 3.92 17.7   3.754  0.0040
#>  X11 - X13     1.17 3.86 18.9   0.303  0.9508
#> 
#> X2 = 0.0, X4 = 2:
#>  contrast  estimate   SE   df t.ratio p.value
#>  X10 - X11     2.27 4.57 24.7   0.497  0.8733
#>  X10 - X13     6.67 4.34 29.6   1.537  0.2885
#>  X11 - X13     4.40 4.76 20.4   0.924  0.6320
#> 
#> X2 = 0.6, X4 = 2:
#>  contrast  estimate   SE   df t.ratio p.value
#>  X10 - X11     2.27 4.57 24.7   0.497  0.8733
#>  X10 - X13     6.67 4.34 29.6   1.537  0.2885
#>  X11 - X13     4.40 4.76 20.4   0.924  0.6320
#> 
#> X2 = 0.8, X4 = 2:
#>  contrast  estimate   SE   df t.ratio p.value
#>  X10 - X11     2.27 4.57 24.7   0.497  0.8733
#>  X10 - X13     6.67 4.34 29.6   1.537  0.2885
#>  X11 - X13     4.40 4.76 20.4   0.924  0.6320
#> 
#> X2 = 1.0, X4 = 2:
#>  contrast  estimate   SE   df t.ratio p.value
#>  X10 - X11     5.42 3.83 21.4   1.412  0.3525
#>  X10 - X13     2.45 3.56 28.9   0.689  0.7720
#>  X11 - X13    -2.96 3.90 19.8  -0.760  0.7311
#> 
#> Results are averaged over the levels of: X5 
#> P value adjustment: tukey method for comparing a family of 3 estimates

I've had no problem obtaining the model coefficient + associated stats from the mice package using summary(pool(yPsy1)). Everything looks good.
I ran this with my Large Mira object (obtained with the previous model) to obtain my emmeans:
emmeans(yPsy1, pairwise ~ X1|X2|X4)

THE PROBLEM: Although X2 is a factor (0, 1), emmeans gives me additional levels (0, 0.6, 0.8, 1). There are even more levels when I considered my 25 imputes datasets.
This variable was imputed, but I inspected my 25 imputed dataset (df.mids) and can't see these values. I also checked the individual 25 frames in my Mira model element, and all I see is 0 and 1. Also, the mixed linear model outputs give me only 2 levels, which is normal.
Could you tell me where I went wrong and how to fix this?
I was redirected from Cross Validated where someone suggested that emmeans may be considering X2 as a numeric value. So, rather then specifying as.factor in my lmer(), I should try modifying my variable in my imputed dataframe. So I did :
Same initial data set
df.mids2<-as.mids(long=df2, .imp="imp")
df.mids2$X2<-as.factor(df.mids2$X2)
yPsy2 <- with(data = df.mids2, exp = lme4::lmer(Dependant ~ factor(X1) + factor(X2) + X3 +factor(X4) +factor(X5) + factor(X1) * factor(X2) + 
factor(X2) * factor(X4) + factor(X1) * factor(X4) +
factor(X1) * factor(X2) * factor(X4) + (1| Subj)), reml=TRUE)
mice.res <- summary(pool(yPsy2))
mice.res
#>                                   term    estimate std.error   statistic
#> 1                          (Intercept)  25.9340792 7.8864719  3.28842599
#> 2                          factor(X1)1 -11.0168803 6.1641328 -1.78725552
#> 3                          factor(X1)3 -12.8614164 6.5151402 -1.97408128
#> 4                          factor(X2)1   7.6964991 7.2210293  1.06584516
#> 5                                   X3  -0.1129837 0.1455105 -0.77646422
#> 6                          factor(X4)2  -6.6860358 7.3265611 -0.91257490
#> 7                          factor(X5)2   6.7636729 4.4682356  1.51372343
#> 8              factor(X1)1:factor(X2)1  -2.5189278 7.1551292 -0.35204505
#> 9              factor(X1)3:factor(X2)1  -1.8445553 7.8818619 -0.23402533
#> 10             factor(X2)1:factor(X4)2  -4.2784766 8.7986350 -0.48626595
#> 11             factor(X1)1:factor(X4)2   8.7468803 7.6738824  1.13982465
#> 12             factor(X1)3:factor(X4)2   6.1926579 7.7724684  0.79674276
#> 13 factor(X1)1:factor(X2)1:factor(X4)2  -0.6267509 9.4682741 -0.06619485
#> 14 factor(X1)3:factor(X2)1:factor(X4)2   6.0615966 9.6874709  0.62571507
#>          df    p.value
#> 1  36.93801 0.00221774
#> 2  42.12344 0.08109302
#> 3  34.16544 0.05650184
#> 4  31.15342 0.29468469
#> 5  34.29064 0.44279816
#> 6  36.25076 0.36749560
#> 7  41.83535 0.13761496
#> 8  40.67191 0.72662209
#> 9  25.35173 0.81684491
#> 10 36.72275 0.62966797
#> 11 39.75094 0.26118111
#> 12 37.82968 0.43057262
#> 13 34.49832 0.94760483
#> 14 30.61215 0.53613943

emmeans(yPsy2, pairwise ~ X1|X2|X4)
#> $emmeans
#> X2 = 0.0, X4 = 1:
#>  X1 emmean   SE   df lower.CL upper.CL
#>   0   25.0 6.58 18.0   11.152     38.8
#>   1   13.9 6.56 18.1    0.172     27.7
#>   3   12.1 6.18 21.7   -0.732     24.9
#> 
#> X2 = 0.6, X4 = 1:
#>  X1 emmean   SE   df lower.CL upper.CL
#>   0   25.0 6.58 18.0   11.152     38.8
#>   1   13.9 6.56 18.1    0.172     27.7
#>   3   12.1 6.18 21.7   -0.732     24.9
#> 
#> X2 = 0.8, X4 = 1:
#>  X1 emmean   SE   df lower.CL upper.CL
#>   0   25.0 6.58 18.0   11.152     38.8
#>   1   13.9 6.56 18.1    0.172     27.7
#>   3   12.1 6.18 21.7   -0.732     24.9
#> 
#> X2 = 1.0, X4 = 1:
#>  X1 emmean   SE   df lower.CL upper.CL
#>   0   32.7 3.65 21.4   25.071     40.3
#>   1   19.1 3.85 18.1   11.037     27.2
#>   3   18.0 3.97 16.1    9.540     26.4
#> 
#> X2 = 0.0, X4 = 2:
#>  X1 emmean   SE   df lower.CL upper.CL
#>   0   18.3 4.68 20.9    8.540     28.0
#>   1   16.0 5.01 16.9    5.437     26.6
#>   3   11.6 4.68 20.8    1.869     21.4
#> 
#> X2 = 0.6, X4 = 2:
#>  X1 emmean   SE   df lower.CL upper.CL
#>   0   18.3 4.68 20.9    8.540     28.0
#>   1   16.0 5.01 16.9    5.437     26.6
#>   3   11.6 4.68 20.8    1.869     21.4
#> 
#> X2 = 0.8, X4 = 2:
#>  X1 emmean   SE   df lower.CL upper.CL
#>   0   18.3 4.68 20.9    8.540     28.0
#>   1   16.0 5.01 16.9    5.437     26.6
#>   3   11.6 4.68 20.8    1.869     21.4
#> 
#> X2 = 1.0, X4 = 2:
#>  X1 emmean   SE   df lower.CL upper.CL
#>   0   21.7 3.42 23.1   14.630     28.8
#>   1   16.3 3.72 17.3    8.434     24.1
#>   3   19.2 3.50 21.7   11.981     26.5
#> 
#> Results are averaged over the levels of: X5 
#> Confidence level used: 0.95 
#> 
#> $contrasts
#> X2 = 0.0, X4 = 1:
#>  contrast  estimate   SE   df t.ratio p.value
#>  X10 - X11    11.02 6.16 30.2   1.787  0.1909
#>  X10 - X13    12.86 6.52 25.1   1.974  0.1394
#>  X11 - X13     1.84 6.50 25.4   0.284  0.9567
#> 
#> X2 = 0.6, X4 = 1:
#>  contrast  estimate   SE   df t.ratio p.value
#>  X10 - X11    11.02 6.16 30.2   1.787  0.1909
#>  X10 - X13    12.86 6.52 25.1   1.974  0.1394
#>  X11 - X13     1.84 6.50 25.4   0.284  0.9567
#> 
#> X2 = 0.8, X4 = 1:
#>  contrast  estimate   SE   df t.ratio p.value
#>  X10 - X11    11.02 6.16 30.2   1.787  0.1909
#>  X10 - X13    12.86 6.52 25.1   1.974  0.1394
#>  X11 - X13     1.84 6.50 25.4   0.284  0.9567
#> 
#> X2 = 1.0, X4 = 1:
#>  contrast  estimate   SE   df t.ratio p.value
#>  X10 - X11    13.54 3.63 25.1   3.725  0.0028
#>  X10 - X13    14.71 3.92 17.7   3.754  0.0040
#>  X11 - X13     1.17 3.86 18.9   0.303  0.9508
#> 
#> X2 = 0.0, X4 = 2:
#>  contrast  estimate   SE   df t.ratio p.value
#>  X10 - X11     2.27 4.57 24.7   0.497  0.8733
#>  X10 - X13     6.67 4.34 29.6   1.537  0.2885
#>  X11 - X13     4.40 4.76 20.4   0.924  0.6320
#> 
#> X2 = 0.6, X4 = 2:
#>  contrast  estimate   SE   df t.ratio p.value
#>  X10 - X11     2.27 4.57 24.7   0.497  0.8733
#>  X10 - X13     6.67 4.34 29.6   1.537  0.2885
#>  X11 - X13     4.40 4.76 20.4   0.924  0.6320
#> 
#> X2 = 0.8, X4 = 2:
#>  contrast  estimate   SE   df t.ratio p.value
#>  X10 - X11     2.27 4.57 24.7   0.497  0.8733
#>  X10 - X13     6.67 4.34 29.6   1.537  0.2885
#>  X11 - X13     4.40 4.76 20.4   0.924  0.6320
#> 
#> X2 = 1.0, X4 = 2:
#>  contrast  estimate   SE   df t.ratio p.value
#>  X10 - X11     5.42 3.83 21.4   1.412  0.3525
#>  X10 - X13     2.45 3.56 28.9   0.689  0.7720
#>  X11 - X13    -2.96 3.90 19.8  -0.760  0.7311
#> 
#> Results are averaged over the levels of: X5 
#> P value adjustment: tukey method for comparing a family of 3 estimates

I also tried emmeans(yPsy1, pairwise ~ factor(X1)|factor(X2)|factor(X4)) and the results did not change.

This is a reasonable question but would be much easier to answer with a [mcve] ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

@BenBolker , I thank you for replying. I added the reprex. I hope it is what you expected. It's my first time posting here. Let me know if I could provide other useful informations.

@Alexandra Chapdelaine would it be possible to do dput(df1) and edit the question to include the output of that?

@JoshAllen Done, I hope this is what you needed.

Simply convert the variables to factors before fitting the model:
df1 <- datawizard::to_factor(df1, c("X1", "X2", "X4", "X5"))

# impute missing values
df.mids1 <- as.mids(long = df1, .imp = "imp")
yPsy2 <- with(data = df.mids1, exp = lme4::lmer(Dependant ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 + X5 +
    X1 * X2 + X2 * X4 + X1 * X4 + X1 * X2 * X4 + (1 | Subj)))
mice.res <- summary(pool(yPsy2))
mice.res

emmeans::emmeans(yPsy2, pairwise ~ X1 | X2 | X4)

A "longer" solution, which requires a hack: the ggeffects packages automatically detects the variable type used in the model and (should) treat it as intended:
library(ggeffects)
library(easystats)
library(lme4)
library(mice)

# ... data set

# impute missing values
df.mids1 <- as.mids(long = df1, .imp = "imp")

# fit models
models <- lapply(1:5, function(i) {
  lme4::lmer(Dependant ~ factor(X1) + factor(X2) +
               X3 +
               factor(X4) +
               factor(X5) +
               factor(X1) * factor(X2) +
               factor(X2) * factor(X4) +
               factor(X1) * factor(X4) +
               factor(X1) * factor(X2) * factor(X4) +
               (1 | Subj), data = mice::complete(df.mids1, action = i))
})
# pooled estimates
pool_parameters(models)
#> # Fixed Effects
#> 
#> Parameter                          | Coefficient |   SE |          95% CI | Statistic |    df |     p
#> -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#> (Intercept)                        |       25.93 | 7.89 | [  9.95, 41.91] |      3.29 | 36.94 | 0.002
#> X1 [1]                             |      -11.02 | 6.16 | [-23.46,  1.42] |     -1.79 | 42.12 | 0.081
#> X1 [3]                             |      -12.86 | 6.52 | [-26.10,  0.38] |     -1.97 | 34.17 | 0.057
#> X2 [1]                             |        7.70 | 7.22 | [ -7.03, 22.42] |      1.07 | 31.15 | 0.295
#> X3                                 |       -0.11 | 0.15 | [ -0.41,  0.18] |     -0.78 | 34.29 | 0.443
#> X4 [2]                             |       -6.69 | 7.33 | [-21.54,  8.17] |     -0.91 | 36.25 | 0.367
#> X5 [2]                             |        6.76 | 4.47 | [ -2.25, 15.78] |      1.51 | 41.84 | 0.138
#> X1 [1] × factor(X2)1               |       -2.52 | 7.16 | [-16.97, 11.93] |     -0.35 | 40.67 | 0.727
#> X1 [3] × factor(X2)1               |       -1.84 | 7.88 | [-18.07, 14.38] |     -0.23 | 25.35 | 0.817
#> X2 [1] × factor(X4)2               |       -4.28 | 8.80 | [-22.11, 13.55] |     -0.49 | 36.72 | 0.630
#> X1 [1] × factor(X4)2               |        8.75 | 7.67 | [ -6.77, 24.26] |      1.14 | 39.75 | 0.261
#> X1 [3] × factor(X4)2               |        6.19 | 7.77 | [ -9.54, 21.93] |      0.80 | 37.83 | 0.431
#> X1 [1] × factor(X2)1 × factor(X4)2 |       -0.63 | 9.47 | [-19.86, 18.60] |     -0.07 | 34.50 | 0.948
#> X1 [3] × factor(X2)1 × factor(X4)2 |        6.06 | 9.69 | [-13.71, 25.83] |      0.63 | 30.61 | 0.536
#> 
#> Uncertainty intervals (equal-tailed) and p-values (two-tailed) computed
#>   using a Wald distribution approximation.

# do the same for predictions...
predictions <- lapply(1:5, function(i) {
  m <- lme4::lmer(Dependant ~ factor(X1) + factor(X2) +
                    X3 +
                    factor(X4) +
                    factor(X5) +
                    factor(X1) * factor(X2) +
                    factor(X2) * factor(X4) +
                    factor(X1) * factor(X4) +
                    factor(X1) * factor(X2) * factor(X4) +
                    (1 | Subj), data = mice::complete(df.mids1, action = i))
  predict_response(m, c("X1", "X2", "X4"), margin = "marginalmeans")
})
# pooled estimated marginal means
pooled_pr <- pool_predictions(predictions)
pooled_pr
#> # Predicted values of Dependant
#> 
#> X2: 0
#> X4: 1
#> 
#> X1 | Predicted |       95% CI
#> -----------------------------
#> 0  |     24.97 | 12.08, 37.85
#> 1  |     13.95 |  1.09, 26.81
#> 3  |     12.10 | -0.02, 24.23
#> 
#> X2: 0
#> X4: 2
#> 
#> X1 | Predicted |       95% CI
#> -----------------------------
#> 0  |     18.28 |  9.10, 27.46
#> 1  |     16.01 |  6.19, 25.83
#> 3  |     11.61 |  2.43, 20.79
#> 
#> X2: 1
#> X4: 1
#> 
#> X1 | Predicted |       95% CI
#> -----------------------------
#> 0  |     32.66 | 25.50, 39.82
#> 1  |     19.13 | 11.58, 26.68
#> 3  |     17.96 | 10.17, 25.74
#> 
#> X2: 1
#> X4: 2
#> 
#> X1 | Predicted |       95% CI
#> -----------------------------
#> 0  |     21.70 | 15.00, 28.40
#> 1  |     16.28 |  8.98, 23.58
#> 3  |     19.25 | 12.39, 26.11
#> 
#> Adjusted for:
#> * X3 = 38.50

# This is a hack! The `test_predictions` function needs information from the
# original model object (like, linear model, mixed model etc.), which is not
# available in the pooled object. Thus, we simply fit a single model again
# to have "m" in the environment - "m" is the name we used in the loop above.
m <- lme4::lmer(Dependant ~ factor(X1) + factor(X2) +
                  X3 +
                  factor(X4) +
                  factor(X5) +
                  factor(X1) * factor(X2) +
                  factor(X2) * factor(X4) +
                  factor(X1) * factor(X4) +
                  factor(X1) * factor(X2) * factor(X4) +
                  (1 | Subj), data = mice::complete(df.mids1, action = 1))

# test predictions (pairwise comparisons), grouped by X2 and X4
test_predictions(pooled_pr, by = c("X2", "X4"), engine = "ggeffects")
#> # Pairwise comparisons
#> 
#> X2/X4 = 0.1
#> 
#> X1  | Contrast |        95% CI |     p
#> --------------------------------------
#> 0-1 |    11.02 |  -7.70, 29.74 | 0.242
#> 0-3 |    12.86 |  -5.33, 31.05 | 0.161
#> 1-3 |     1.84 | -16.33, 20.02 | 0.839
#> 
#> X2/X4 = 1.1
#> 
#> X1  | Contrast |        95% CI |     p
#> --------------------------------------
#> 0-1 |    13.54 |   2.84, 24.24 | 0.014
#> 0-3 |    14.71 |   3.83, 25.58 | 0.009
#> 1-3 |     1.17 |  -9.98, 12.32 | 0.833
#> 
#> X2/X4 = 0.2
#> 
#> X1  | Contrast |        95% CI |     p
#> --------------------------------------
#> 0-1 |     2.27 | -11.55, 16.09 | 0.742
#> 0-3 |     6.67 |  -6.68, 20.01 | 0.319
#> 1-3 |     4.40 |  -9.42, 18.22 | 0.525
#> 
#> X2/X4 = 1.2
#> 
#> X1  | Contrast |        95% CI |     p
#> --------------------------------------
#> 0-1 |     5.42 |  -4.77, 15.60 | 0.290
#> 0-3 |     2.45 |  -7.41, 12.31 | 0.619
#> 1-3 |    -2.96 | -13.27,  7.34 | 0.565

Created on 2024-09-02 with reprex v2.1.1

Thank you for this solution! The first option worked just fine!

It appears that the mice package interprets X2 etc. as covariates and ignores that you coerced them to factors in the model statement. So I suggest reporting this to the developers as a bug, because you are not getting meaningful results from the multiple imputation, regardless of whether or not you're using emmeans.

I'm not sure this is a bug in mice. The package treats the data as provided by the user, so you have to explicitly convert your variables into the appropriate type before imputing missing values. It's similar like for lm(), where the function also needs to know the variable type, if all imported data from csv files are numeric by default.

@daniel I see your point, but if so, what went wrong, in that the multiple imputation is clearly incorrect?

I think the data / variables were all numeric during imputation and coerced to factor later in the formula. The original data was still numeric after model fitting, I think.
